# build static library for iOS on windows

Tags: objective-c, windows, static-libraries, gnustep

I want to cross-build a C++ static library on Windows or Linux (*.a), which will be included in Xcode 4, and finally used in iOS app. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. At the very least, you need to compile your library for armv7 & armv7s (which probably cannot be done on windows) and then i386 for the simulator. Why can't you simply do this on your mac?

Comment: I tried gnustep, but i'm not sure which compile or link flags i should  use. when i build a static library(the language was C),i moved to Mac, add into xCode 4 project, it can't work.

Comment: For some reason I can't copy source code from windows(that machine). May be it's a difficult thing. I should use another way to do it. Perhaps install a Mac in VM.